# How to use the Common/StandardStyles in a C# WinRT project?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm working on a WinRT project in C#

I wanted to use things like: `{StaticResource EditAppBarButtonStyle}`
this is defined in `Common/StandardStyles.xaml`

but when I try to compile my project I get the error that the resource could not be resolved.
I guess I need to add the `Common/StandardStyles.xaml` but I dont know how

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/595ab2a9-9d59-4197-b49d-687655811ae1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I just needed to remove the `<!-- ... -->` in the `Common/StandardStyles.xaml`

Answer (score 0):

A few years too late, but maybe helpful to someone else who stumbles on this question from a bing search:  For a Windows 8.1 app, that's not how you do it anymore.

Since most people never used most of the styles in StandardStyles.xaml, this file was removed for performance reasons.  In Windows 8.1, you use an AppBarButton like

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Edit" Label="Edit" />
```

Info taken from [this blog post right here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2013/10/29/remove-standardstyles-xaml-from-windows-8-1-winrt-projects.aspx)